# How to set an organization's public home page as startpage of your liferay portal

Tags: liferay, administration, liferay-6

Once you deployed liferay, how do you change the default home url? Standard is that it forwards to the guest community, but I would like to change that url to an organization's public page home-url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it by using the "Virtual Hosts" option provided through Liferay.  On each community's settings, you can define a "virtual host" value.  If Liferay receives a request coming with a URL that matches a community's virtual host, that community's content will be served.

For example, my Liferay server may be hosted on "`my-liferay-server`" - but has 3 communities - "guest", "site1" with a virtual host configured of "`site1.example.com`", and "site2" with a virtual host configured of "`site2.example.com`".  These additional DNS names all point to "`my-liferay-server`".  As Liferay receives each request, it looks at the requested host name, and forwards to the proper community.

Note that Liferay only supports one "Virtual Host" value per community - so unfortunately, you can't have both "`site1.example.com`" and "`site3.example.com`" served by the same community by Liferay itself.  This can be accomplished, but requires fronting the Liferay instance with something else like an Apache HTTP Server instance, using mod_rewrite rules.

Additionally, assuming that each community has a page with a URL name of `/home`, I have the following rewrite rule in such an Apache HTTP Server instance:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /home [PT,L]
```

This ensures that the root of each virtual host is served by each community's "home page".

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be accomplished by editing the following portal property:

```
#
# This sets the default home URL of the portal.
#
company.default.home.url=/web/my-organization
```

Where /my-organization is the Friendly URL of your organization, which can be configured in the Settings of your organization.